# Show used config and parameter files

Tags: symfony

Is there a way to show via command line in symfony to show which all config-files and parameter-files are used in a specific environment?

Can't find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know - there is no such command. But you can use command

```
php bin/console debug:config
```

to see your current configuration. If you run it without parameters, output will have list of bundles. You can pick name from that list and will be able to see parameters of specific bundle.

There is also this command

```
php bin/console debug:container --parameters
```

which will output parameters.

You can also manually traverse configuration. Symfony transparently loads `config_<env>.yml`, which imports all other files, including `config.yml`

Comment: In addition to @svgrafov answer, you can use 
`php bin/console debug:container --parameter=kernel.environment`
if you want to check the environment variable (dev or prod).

Also `php bin/console config:dump-reference framework` - will give you information about the standard symfony framework configuration. 

Or you can check the configuration of the exact bundle, i.e. FOSUserBundle with alias fos_user:
`php bin/console config:dump-reference fos_user`

Comment: ./bin/console config:dump XYZ  prints the default only, correct? Not your modifications.